# How can I get the average of lists in many columns of data.frame

Tags: r

```
dput(head(P[,1:2],12))

structure(list(valoracion.c1 = list(c(0.75, 1, 1), c(0.75, 1, 
1), c(0.75, 1, 1), c(0.75, 1, 1), c(0.75, 1, 1), c(0.5, 0.75, 
1), c(0.75, 1, 1), c(0.75, 1, 1), c(0.5, 0.75, 1), c(0.75, 1, 
1), c(0.5, 0.75, 1), c(0.75, 1, 1)), valoracion.c2 = list(c(0.75, 
1, 1), c(0.75, 1, 1), c(0.5, 0.75, 1), c(0.75, 1, 1), c(0.75, 
1, 1), c(0.75, 1, 1), c(0.5, 0.75, 1), c(0.75, 1, 1), c(0.25, 
0.5, 0.75), c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), c(0.75, 1, 1), c(0.5, 0.75, 1
))), .Names = c("valoracion.c1", "valoracion.c2"), row.names = c(NA, 
12L), class = "data.frame")
```

## I´d like to get the average for each column and preserve the data structure. I have tried

## somthing like that

> dat2 <- P[1,]
>   dat2[]<-(lapply(P,function(x) list(Reduce(mean,x))))
>    Show Traceback

Rerun with Debug
 Error in mean.default(init, x[[i]]) : 
  'trim' must be numeric of length one

## Could someone help me?

Comment: Could you show the dput output ie. `dput(head(data,12))`

Comment: This is not a data.frame. In R, each column should have a (unique) name.

Comment: It is also not clear from the expected output which values are used for the sum.

Comment: Why do you need list columns in a data.frame? That seems suboptimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the data you showed is similar to the one below:

```
dat2 <- dat1[1,]
dat2[] <- lapply(dat1, function(x) list(Reduce(`+`, x)))
dat2
#       Col1       Col2       Col3
#1 18, 19, 23 20, 15, 25 22, 21, 17


head(dat1,3)
#    Col1    Col2    Col3
#1 2, 1, 3 2, 1, 3 2, 3, 1
#2 2, 1, 3 3, 1, 2 1, 3, 2
#3 1, 2, 3 3, 1, 2 2, 3, 1
```

#### data

```
set.seed(45)
dat1 <- data.frame(Col1=I(lapply(1:10, function(i) sample(3))),
    Col2=I(lapply(1:10, function(i) sample(3))),
    Col3= I(lapply(1:10, function(i) sample(3))))
```